# Where can I go to do basic work on my vehicle?

Tags: maintenance

I live in the middle of a city.  I have a tiny parking spot in an underground parking garage (have to fold the mirrors in just to get in!).  Doing any maintenance is officially verboten, and it wouldn't really be feasible anyway -- there's really no room, poor light, no outlets, etc.

So I want to do a little more maintenance on my own, like oil changes, but I don't have a place to do it.  Is there any type of place that would let someone do basic work on their car?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There do exist these "Fix it Yourself" garages.

You can rent time in a bay with various levels of equipment, with or without a lift, tools, etc.  All affecting the rate of course.

I am not sure how prevelant these are in various areas so you will have to try to search one out if it exists near you, here is an example website of one I found searching http://www.fiygarage.com/home/fiy_garage-home.php

Comment: FYI, if you have access to your local military facility, there's almost always a facility like this either attached to the motor pool or available to the personnel.  They generally provide exactly this sort of thing at a reasonable rate: a workspace, some rental tools, possibly a lift and fluid disposal.

Comment: Ah, "FIY" (and "DIY") are the magic google juice that finds these places, and there's one not too far from me -- thanks!

Comment: FYI the FIY link is broken. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the type of vehicle you have, see if there is a local car club to join and get involved in.

My experience with my club has been very positive.  We love working on our cars and members understand not everyone has the setup to do so or the knowledge.

There will likely be members that are happy to help out with the occasional work.  Be willing to help others too though, it isn't a one way street.  Even if you don't have the knowledge, a second pair of hands will make almost any job easier.

Answer (score 2):

Search for hobby shops. Some of the nicer ones have a lift, and tools.

Comment: This just turns up places selling me knitting supplies and model airplanes.  :-)